# SSDT Signing CLR assembly throws the operation could not be completed

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I created SQL Server database project in Visual Studio 2022. When I try to sign the CLR assembly so I can publish the CLR assembly to the SQL Server database, I am getting `Operation could not be completed`. Does anyone knows what might be an issue or how to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Comment: When does the error dialog appear? When you click the `OK` button on the "Create Strong Name Key" dialog? Or at some other point? Might be a permissions issue for creating the **.pfx** file?

Comment: Yes, the error dialog appear when I click on `OK` button. Is interesting, that even through the error, the `.pfx` file is created in the sql project folder.